# Is there a way to tell Serde to use a struct field as a map's key?

Tags: serialization, rust, yaml, serde

I have a map of items that I would like to serialize to a list of structs, each having a field for the corresponding key.

Imagine having a YAML file like this:

```yaml
name_a:
    some_field: 0
name_b:
    some_field: 0
name_c:
    some_field: 0
```

And a corresponding structure like this:

```rust
struct Item {
    name: String,
    some_field: usize,
}
```

I would like to deserialize the named items into a `Vec<Item>` instead of a `Map<String, Item>`. The item names (`name_a`, ...) are put into the `name` field of the `Item` objects.

I've attempted the following:

```rust
extern crate serde_yaml;
use std::fs::read_to_string;

let contents = read_to_string("file.yml").unwrap();
let items: Vec<Item> = serde_yaml::from_str(&contents).unwrap();
```

This however doesn't work and produces the `invalid type: map, expected a sequence` error.

I'd prefer to avoid creating a transient `Map<String, PartialItem>` that is converted to a `Vec`, and I would also prefer not to implement an additional `PartialItem` struct. Using an `Option<String>` as `name` would be possible, although I don't think this is optimal.

Comment: What should happen when there are duplicate values for `name`? Should it just generate invalid data?

Comment: Good question. I believe YAML suggests duplicate items get overwritten in order, thus the last occurrence is used, other occurrences are dropped. For my use case, this is perfect.

Comment: I'd probably just deserialize to a `Map<String, PartialItem>` and then transform it to a `Vec<Item>`; I assume you are looking to avoid the transient `Map` being created?

Comment: Correct. And I would also prefer not to implement an additional `PartialItem` struct. Using an `Option<String>` as name would be possible for this, although I don't think this is optimal. Maybe the transient `Map` is what I must go for if no better option is available.

Comment: You'll probably have to implement Deserialize it yourself https://serde.rs/deserialize-map.html

Comment: The YAML spec clearly indicates that mapping keys have to be unique. Duplicate keys are invalid, although there are some parser/loader that (some even silently) allow them.

Answer (score 7):

One way is to [deserialize](https://serde.rs/deserialize-map.html) the map yourself:

```
use std::fmt;

use serde::de::{Deserialize, Deserializer, MapAccess, Visitor};
use serde_derive::Deserialize;

struct ItemMapVisitor {}

impl ItemMapVisitor {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {}
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct SomeField {
    some_field: u32,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Item {
    name: String,
    some_field: u32,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct VecItem(Vec<Item>);

impl Item {
    fn new(name: String, some_field: u32) -> Self {
        Self { name, some_field }
    }
}

impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for ItemMapVisitor {
    type Value = VecItem;

    fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        formatter.write_str("name: somefield:")
    }

    fn visit_map<M>(self, mut access: M) -> Result<Self::Value, M::Error>
    where
        M: MapAccess<'de>,
    {
        let mut items = Vec::with_capacity(access.size_hint().unwrap_or(0));
        while let Some((key, value)) = access.next_entry::<String, SomeField>()? {
            items.push(Item::new(key, value.some_field));
        }
        Ok(VecItem(items))
    }
}

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for VecItem {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        deserializer.deserialize_map(ItemMapVisitor::new())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let contents = r#"
name_a:
    some_field: 0
name_b:
    some_field: 1
name_c:
    some_field: 2
"#;

    let items: VecItem = serde_yaml::from_str(&contents).unwrap();
    println!("{:#?}", items);
}
```

Output:

```
VecItem(
    [
        Item {
            name: "name_a",
            some_field: 0
        },
        Item {
            name: "name_b",
            some_field: 1
        },
        Item {
            name: "name_c",
            some_field: 2
        }
    ]
)
```

---

If you don't want of `Somefield` structure. You could also use this:

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Item {
    #[serde(skip)]
    name: String,
    some_field: u32,
}

while let Some((key, value)) = access.next_entry::<String, Item>()? {
    items.push(Item::new(key, value.some_field));
}
```

But this could add some useless copy.

Answer (score 1):

Define a default value for `Item::name` field

```
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Item {
    #[serde(default)]
    name: String,
    some_field: usize,
}
```

With this trick `Item`can be used both for deserializing and for transforming to a `Vec` of `Item`s:

```
let contents = read_to_string("file.yml").unwrap();

let items: HashMap<String, Item> = serde_yaml::from_str(&contents).unwrap();

let slist: Vec<Item> = items
    .into_iter()
    .map(|(k, v)| Item {
        name: k,
        some_field: v.some_field,
    })
    .collect();
```

Comment: OP states that they want to "avoid the transient Map being created"