# Easy translation between struct and map format?

Tags: rust

I have a handful of data objects floating around my code which have a large number of fields of the same type:

```
struct AsStruct {
    mass: i32,
    height: i32,
    energy: i32,
    age: i32,
    radioactivity: i32,
}
```

(actual examples would have more fields - like 20+).

Sometimes but not always, I'm dealing with these fields in a collective way, and it would be better to have something like a `Map<String, i32>`

```
pub const ALL_STATS: [&str; 5] = ["mass", "height", "energy", "age", "radioactivity"];
struct AsMap {
    data: HashMap<String, i32>,
}
```

This latter model lets me treat some things in a neat programmatic way. For instance, below are functions to generate random versions of each:

```
pub fn generate_map() -> AsMap {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    for s in ALL_STATS.iter() {
        map.insert(s.to_string(), rand::random::<i32>() % 10);
    }
    AsMap { data: map }
}

pub fn generate_struct() -> AsStruct {
    AsStruct {
        mass: rand::random::<i32>() % 10,
        height: rand::random::<i32>() % 10,
        energy: rand::random::<i32>() % 10,
        age: rand::random::<i32>() % 10,
        radioactivity: rand::random::<i32>() % 10,
    }
}
```

Obviously, the "Map" version will scale much more easily, and require less refactoring as stats change. On the other hand, there's also times when it's preferable to have the stricter `AsStruct` definition, which can be accessed by more concise syntax and doesn't need extra code to handle missing keys, etc.

I can write translations between the two, or put some set of getters and setters on the `AsStruct` one to allow fields to be treated as keys. This would involve a great deal of boiler plate, however, and feels like a worthy use case for something like a `derive` macro. I can also imagine a lot of additional nice-to-have features that could be added to such a solution, such as typed keys, support for structs with fields of different types, etc.

So my question is: Has this already been solved? Is there a reason this is a bad idea and I should go with one or the other? Is there a standard pattern for having my cake and eating it too in such situations?

Comment: Edited it to remove the part where I asked about existing crates.

Comment: Since your Map is effectively a JSON document, perhaps just `serde` serialization? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53123256/is-there-a-way-to-tell-serde-to-use-a-struct-field-as-a-maps-key

Comment: My instincts tell me it's better to avoid using maps at all, and always keep the information in struct form, and that there are better ways to do the "bad" parts of the structs. However, I cannot tell for sure since you didn't say what exactly you need to do with the data.

Comment: A common, although less than ideal, solution to the problem of generating lots of repeated code is macros. `impl_foo!(mass height energy ...)` can help to shorten things

Comment: I concur with @ChayimFriedman: you'll need to list the fields in any case "to have the stricter AsStruct definition", so you could just as well list them in the struct definition format and implement the map like use cases with macros. This for me is the most idiomatic solution.

Comment: An [iterator over the structs fields](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61978903/442760) gets you part of the way there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the fields of the struct have the same type, then this struct can be considered equivalent to an array.
Then indexing such an array with an enum (one variant per field) is probably similar to the `struct.member` notation.
With the `variant_count` feature (nightly required), we don't have to hard-code the number of variants, then we can be certain that the index is always correct (runtime bound-checking will not be inserted by the compiler).

This is not as convenient as the `struct.member` notation, but it should behave the same (with a bit more verbosity) and still enables iterations on the fields (as with your hash-map).

```rust
#![feature(variant_count)]

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
pub enum ThingField {
    Mass,
    Height,
    Energy,
    Age,
    Radioactivity,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Thing {
    pub fields: [i32; std::mem::variant_count::<ThingField>()],
}
impl Thing {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            fields: [0; std::mem::variant_count::<ThingField>()],
        }
    }
}
impl Default for Thing {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self::new()
    }
}
impl std::ops::Index<ThingField> for Thing {
    type Output = i32;

    fn index(
        &self,
        field: ThingField,
    ) -> &Self::Output {
        &self.fields[field as usize]
    }
}
impl std::ops::IndexMut<ThingField> for Thing {
    fn index_mut(
        &mut self,
        field: ThingField,
    ) -> &mut Self::Output {
        &mut self.fields[field as usize]
    }
}

fn generate_all_fields() -> Thing {
    let mut thing = Thing::new();
    for field in thing.fields.iter_mut() {
        *field = rand::random::<i32>() % 10;
    }
    thing
}

fn generate_specific_fields() -> Thing {
    let mut thing = Thing::new();
    thing[ThingField::Mass] = 10;
    thing[ThingField::Age] = 5;
    thing
}

fn main() {
    let things = [generate_all_fields(), generate_specific_fields()];
    for thing in things.iter() {
        println!(
            "mass: {}  age: {} ~~> {:?}",
            thing[ThingField::Mass],
            thing[ThingField::Age],
            thing
        );
    }
}
/*
mass: 9  age: 0 ~~> Thing { fields: [9, 5, -7, 0, -4] }
mass: 10  age: 5 ~~> Thing { fields: [10, 0, 0, 5, 0] }
*/
```

Comment: Please remove the `get_unchecked()`. The compiler should be able to optimize that just as well, and never add unsafe without measuring. Also, it would be nicer to use `Index` and `IndexMut`, to allow indexing notation.

Comment: If you really want, [you can even use a macro to have field syntax](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6e2a24ab1422892395b0a8c26080ba6a).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Thank you very much for your help. I'm not confident enough to explain the macro_rule by myself. Please feel free to edit the answer, or provide another one of course, if you think this could improve it.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman  Very graceful macro. But why not keep the struct in its original form (rather than using index), I was assuming the original form to be better than the indexed form.